# Does removing a DOM element with an event listener attached cause a memory leak in dart:html?

Tags: dart

Let's say I have many elements and each has its own listener attached to it like so:

```dart
DivElement _container = querySelector("#container");

void _createButtons(int count) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var button = new ButtonElement()
    ..text = "Button #$i";
    button.onClick.listen((_) => print("Clicked #$i."));
    _container.append(button);
  }
}
```

And then at some point I clear the DOM, like so:

```dart
_container.clear();
```

Should I be worried about the 'orphaned' event listeners?

It seems like this is not clear in pure JavaScript (see [Does remove a DOM object (in Javascript) will cause Memory leak if it has event attached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996030/does-remove-a-dom-object-in-javascript-will-cause-memory-leak-if-it-has-event), for example). Looking at Chrome DevTools Timeline, it looks like there are listeners kept around, but I'm not sure if that's related to what I'm asking.

I could, of course, keep around the `StreamSubscription` and cancel it "to be sure", but I don't want to do that if it's not absolutely necessary. It makes the code complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector will remove the listeners (the same way as JS gets rid of unused listeners). You can safely drop the subscriptions if you don't need them anymore.